# Random characters and random colors generator

Tags: java, random, colors

```
public static char randomLetter() {
    Random r = new Random();
    char randomChar = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(26));
    return randomChar;
}

public static Color randomColor(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat(); 
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
    return randomColor;
}
```

I have these two methods. One returns a random letter in the alphabet and the other returns a random color.
How do I edit these methods so that `randomLetter()` only returns a letter once and not return two of the same letters?

How do I make my `randomColor()` only return random colors between `RED`, `YELLOW`, `GREEN`, or `BLUE`?

Comment: there is a reason it's `random`

Comment: What do you mean by **"between"**? Are `RED`, `YELLOW`, `GREEN`, and `BLUE` the only options, and you want to pick 1 each time?

Comment: if you want to "generate" each element only once, placed all off them in `Queue` shuffle queue and then poll element when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random selection can contain duplicates.  If you don't want duplicates, what you want is a shuffle.

Here's one way to do this.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ShuffleTest {

    private static boolean shuffleLetters = true;
    private static boolean shuffleColors = true;

    private static int shuffleLetterIndex = 0;
    private static int shuffleColorIndex = 0;

    private static List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(shuffleLetter());
        System.out.println(shuffleLetter());
        System.out.println(shuffleLetter());

        System.out.println(shuffleColor());
        System.out.println(shuffleColor());
        System.out.println(shuffleColor());
    }

    public static char shuffleLetter() {
        if (shuffleLetters) {
            int start = (int) 'a';
            int end = (int) 'z';
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                letters.add(Character.valueOf((char) i));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(letters);
            shuffleLetters = false;
        }

        return letters.get(shuffleLetterIndex++);
    }

    public static Color shuffleColor() {
        if (shuffleColors) {
            colors.add(Color.RED);
            colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
            colors.add(Color.GREEN);
            colors.add(Color.BLUE);
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
            shuffleColors = false;
        }

        return colors.get(shuffleColorIndex++);
    }

}
```

Comment: on the code, what are you doing when setting `shuffleLetters  = false` ? I don't know anything about shuffle so what are you doing when you typed `Collections.shuffle(letters);` ?

Comment: @Kisuna97: shuffleLetters is a first time switch.  The first time the method is called, it creates and shuffles the letters before returning the first letter.  On subsequent calls, the method return the next letter in the List.  Shuffling a List is like shuffling a deck of cards.  You still have 52 cards, just in a different order.

Comment: I also don't get why your using the `shuffleColors` in the if statement and then setting it to false later near the end of the `if` statement

Comment: @Kisuna97: Because, as I said before, I only have to shuffle the List **once**.  Not twice, not thrice.  Once.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `enum` instead:

```
public enum ColorCode {     
  RED('r'), 
  YELLOW('y'),
  GREEN('g'),
  BLUE('b');

  public final char code;      

  public char getColorCode() {
    return this.code;
  }

  ColorCode(char code) {
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```